# Applying for Schengen visa while visiting UK

Tags: visas, schengen, south-african-citizens

Is it possible to apply for a Schengen visitor visa with my South African passport whilst in the UK? I am the partner/married to a UK passport holder & citizen.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how long you are in the UK.

> To apply for a Schengen visa from the UK **you must be a UK resident for
>   at least three months**. If this condition is not fulfilled, the
>   Consulate of your country of preference will hardly take the
>   application into consideration.
>
> Non-residents such as travelers and tourists who plan on staying in
>   the UK for 3 months or less should be discouraged from applying for a
>   Schengen visa from within the UK. Instead, they should apply in their
>   home country so that the application is processed, chances of getting
>   a positive answer become greater.

[Source](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/apply-from-uk/)

Comment: I will be in the UK for 5 months on a visitors visa.Am presently in South africa but ticket for Europe travel is required if I were to apply for schengen visa here. We havent booked anything as we are not sure of dates but were only looking at June/July. I leave for the UK March. Even if I had tickets for European travel thats way ahead & imagine the schengen visa would only be dated for 30 days travel( from now )or so if I were to apply here, which is then a waste. So in a quandry of sorts

Comment: As a family member of an EU citizen the rules are more relaxed, I think.

Comment: I wont be able to apply here in South africa as we intend only to travel June/July & you cant apply more than 3 months in advance. I really hope I can apply in the UK...